# fast mobile QR-code to only save a UUID

Tags: android, ios, qr-code

I need a barcode scanner for my mobile apps which works really fast and also with bad lightning conditions. As I only need to store UUIDs and not complete URLs etc., I guess there should be a possibility to limit the value range and therefore make the QR codes better recognizable. Is there a format which supports this?

I also find the WhatsApp QR-Code scanner very fast but I didn't find what they are using exactly...

Comment: Is QR code not good enough? e.g. not scanned fast enough? Hint: you can adjust the complexity of QR code by changing the error correction levels: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Error_correction

Answer (score 0):

One introduction might be [this blogpost](https://www.varvet.com/blog/android-qr-code-reader-made-easy/). It's based on Google's mobile vision api under the namespace `com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode`. It's fast, robust and easy to work with.

And I would also up the error correction level of the generated QR-codes if possible... But try the project linked in the blogpost first to see if you even need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library [barcodescanner](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner)

With bad lightning conditions you can activate the flash, in the library there is all about it.